# How to install Android SDK on Linux using CLI only?

Tags: android, linux, command-line, continuous-integration

I'm setting up an auto build server, and need to install an Android SDK. I'm working over SSH, of course. But `tools/android update sdk` wants to start a Java GUI. Any other way to install an SDK?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you use `tools/android -h update sdk` (I discovered that by trying `tools/android update sdk --help`), you will get a list of options for the `update sdk` command, the most interesting one being:

```
  -u --no-ui    Updates from command-line (does not display the GUI)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Be prepared though once you run the command it's going to download all available platforms.

Comment: It doesn't work for sdk r19 on linux. Any suggestions? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/q/10941549/563306

Answer (score 6):

`tools/android update sdk --no-ui`

Answer (score 1):

If workwing behind a proxy consider using options:

```
 --proxy-port: HTTP/HTTPS proxy port (overrides settings if defined)

 --proxy-host: HTTP/HTTPS proxy host (overrides settings if defined)
```

Comment: ... without the colon, otherwise you get an error. 
Like this:   --proxy-port 8888  (I just made that error)