# install android sdk using command line linux

Tags: android, database, linux, debugging, command-line

I want to download android sdk through command line.
I got this command from command https://stackoverflow.com/a/4569792/563306
I downloaded Android SDK r18 tar file. extracted it and in tools directory,

I tried this command

```
>android update sdk --no-ui
```

It gives an error,

```
Error: Flag '--no-ui' is not valid for 'update sdk'.
```

Also, I don't see the --no-ui options in the

```
android --help
```

Did Google change the command line options

When I did a help, I get this,

```
android --help update sdk

Usage:
  android [global options] action [action options]

Global options:
  -v --verbose  Verbose mode: errors, warnings and informational messages are printed.
  -h --help     Help on a specific command.
  -s --silent   Silent mode: only errors are printed out.

Valid actions are composed of a verb and an optional direct object:
-   list             : Lists existing targets or virtual devices.
-   list avd         : Lists existing Android Virtual Devices.
-   list target      : Lists existing targets.
- create avd         : Creates a new Android Virtual Device.
-   move avd         : Moves or renames an Android Virtual Device.
- delete avd         : Deletes an Android Virtual Device.
- update avd         : Updates an Android Virtual Device to match the folders of a new SDK.
- create project     : Creates a new Android Project.
- update project     : Updates an Android Project (must have an AndroidManifest.xml).
- create test-project: Creates a new Android Test Project.
- update test-project: Updates an Android Test Project (must have an AndroidManifest.xml).
- create lib-project : Creates a new Android Library Project.
- update lib-project : Updates an Android Library Project (must have an AndroidManifest.xml).
- update adb         : Updates adb to support the USB devices declared in the SDK add-ons.
- update sdk         : Updates the SDK by suggesting new platforms to install if available.


Action "list ":
  Lists existing targets or virtual devices.
Options:
  No options

Action "list avd":
  Lists existing Android Virtual Devices.
Options:
  No options

Action "list target":
  Lists existing targets.
Options:
  No options

Action "create avd":
  Creates a new Android Virtual Device.
Options:
  -c --sdcard   Path to a shared SD card image, or size of a new sdcard for the new AVD
  -t --target   Target id of the new AVD [required]
  -n --name     Name of the new AVD [required]
  -p --path     Location path of the directory where the new AVD will be created
  -f --force    Force creation (override an existing AVD)
  -s --skin     Skin of the new AVD

Action "move avd":
  Moves or renames an Android Virtual Device.
Options:
  -p --path     New location path of the directory where to move the AVD
  -n --name     Name of the AVD to move or rename [required]
  -r --rename   New name of the AVD to rename

Action "delete avd":
  Deletes an Android Virtual Device.
Options:
  -n --name     Name of the AVD to delete [required]

Action "update avd":
  Updates an Android Virtual Device to match the folders of a new SDK.
Options:
  -n --name     Name of the AVD to update [required]

Action "create project":
  Creates a new Android Project.
Options:
  -n --name     Project name
  -t --target   Target id of the new project [required]
  -p --path     Location path of new project [required]
  -k --package  Package name [required]
  -a --activity Activity name [required]

Action "update project":
  Updates an Android Project (must have an AndroidManifest.xml).
Options:
  -p --path     Location path of the project [required]
  -l --library  Location path of an Android Library to add, relative to the main project
  -n --name     Project name
  -t --target   Target id to set for the project
  -s --subprojects Also update any projects in sub-folders, such as test projects.

Action "create test-project":
  Creates a new Android Test Project.
Options:
  -p --path     Location path of new project [required]
  -m --main     Location path of the project to test, relative to the new project [required]
  -n --name     Project name

Action "update test-project":
  Updates an Android Test Project (must have an AndroidManifest.xml).
Options:
  -m --main     Location path of the project to test, relative to the new project [required]
  -p --path     Location path of the project [required]

Action "create lib-project":

  Creates a new Android Library Project.
Options:
  -n --name     Project name
  -p --path     Location path of new project [required]
  -t --target   Target id of the new project [required]
  -k --package  Package name [required]

Action "update lib-project":
  Updates an Android Library Project (must have an AndroidManifest.xml).
Options:
  -p --path     Location path of the project [required]
  -l --library  Location path of an Android Library to add, relative to the main project
  -t --target   Target id to set for the project

Action "update adb":
  Updates adb to support the USB devices declared in the SDK add-ons.
Options:
  No options

Action "update sdk":
  Updates the SDK by suggesting new platforms to install if available.
Options:
  No options
```

Comment: There is a typo in the command: `udpate` -> `update`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It works fine for me. Try it without the `--no-ui` flag and see if that works. If not, what is the error message you get?

---

### Edit:

You probably have your `PATH` configured incorrectly. You need to execute the "current folder executable" as follows:

```
$ ./android update sdk --no-ui
```

Comment: I meant what is the error message when you do it without the `--no-ui` flag.

Comment: It tries to launch the GUI. But I want to download using the command line only.

Comment: Maybe you should try over with a clean download? Or perhaps try an older version? It works fine on my machine.

Comment: I wish... Is there a way to download previous versions of SDK?

Comment: I went to the directory android-sdk and typed tools/android update sdk --no-ui and it worked. It doesn't work when I go inside the tools directory and run the command

Comment: Cool. I updated my answer in case someone else runs into the same issue :).

Comment: C'mon. This is not an **generic issue**. There would be something wrong in your env, because it doesn't matter which is your current directory to suport some other options.

Comment: @dcanh121: I think you have another version of android in your `PATH` environment variable, and that it is the version that is launched when you try `android`. If you want to execute the "current folder executable", you have to type `./android`.

Comment: @Jean Hominal Yes, I have another SDK in a different folder. Probably its set in the PATH. ./android works like a charm. sry, my bad.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Android SDK Tools Rev 19 you should get

```
$ android --help update sdk

       Usage:
       android [global options] update sdk [action options]
       Global options:
  -h --help    : Help on a specific command.
  -v --verbose : Verbose mode, shows errors, warnings and all messages.
  -s --silent  : Silent mode, shows errors only.

                     Action "update sdk":
  Updates the SDK by suggesting new platforms to install if available.
Options:
     --proxy-port: HTTP/HTTPS proxy port (overrides settings if defined)
     --proxy-host: HTTP/HTTPS proxy host (overrides settings if defined)
  -s --no-https  : Uses HTTP instead of HTTPS (the default) for downloads.
  -a --all       : Includes all packages (such as obsolete and non-dependent
                   ones.)
  -f --force     : Forces replacement of a package or its parts, even if
                   something has been modified.
  -u --no-ui     : Updates from command-line (does not display the GUI)
  -p --obsolete  : Deprecated. Please use --all instead.
  -t --filter    : A filter that limits the update to the specified types of
                   packages in the form of a comma-separated list of
                   [platform, system-image, tool, platform-tool, doc, sample,
                   source]. This also accepts the identifiers returned by
                   'list sdk --extended'.
  -n --dry-mode  : Simulates the update but does not download or install
                   anything.
```

and `-u` or `--no-ui` is one of the options.

Comment: I don't see that option. I updated the question with what I get. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the important option missed is --version

Comment: It worked when I ran the command  tools/android update sdk --no-ui from the android-sdk directory. But it didnt work when I went inside the tools directory and ran android update sdk --no-ui

Answer (score 0):

Just to add. When you use the proxy options do **not** supply the http:// part. The android executable will not complain, and will report everything downloaded ok. I was on a completely new install and was sure nothing was downloaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

Its so simple:

```
# ./android update sdk -u
```