# android: Exception in org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]

Tags: android, ubuntu, command-line, adt

I'm trying to setup an environment in which I can develop android apps on an Ubuntu *server* 13.04. Therefore, I can only use the command line.

When I run `android`, just to check if it's working, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.createShell(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.java:168)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.open(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.java:137)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.SdkUpdaterWindow.open(SdkUpdaterWindow.java:111)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:356)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:120)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

What I've done so far:

- `apt-get install ant`
- Downloaded the "ADT bundle" from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
- Unpacked it in my home directory `/home/camilstaps`
- Added `/home/camilstaps/adt-bundle-linux/tools` to my `PATH` environment variable

What can I do to solve this exception?

Comment: Also related (not to exception encountered, but additional details on installing from command line): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941549/install-android-sdk-using-command-line-linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here was that `android` tried to open a graphical display, which it couldn't. `android` simply cannot be runned on a server without a graphical screen.

However, with some parameters, `android` *can* be used. For example, see [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html):

```
android create project \
--target <target_ID> \
--name <your_project_name> \
--path path/to/your/project \
--activity <your_activity_name> \
--package <your_package_namespace>
```

Comment: noticed the same behavior, when running it as `su username` (which has no session with the GDM and therefore no `DISPLAY` under `X`). could imagine, it might still work - while assigning the display for output, before running `./android`.

Comment: @syslogic you could try to use `sudo -E -u username`, then you keep your own environment.

Comment: think that `export DISPLAY=:0` or `export DISPLAY=:0.0` should select the first available display, while there is any ongoing `X11` (gdm) session. one can also select VNC displays like that, when running headless.

Comment: the answer here explains how to authenticate the display: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180585/110101; the condition `ForwardX11 yes` should also be relevant, to obtain any valid display for output... just noticed, that the `./android` command had been obsoleted meanwhile, it's `tools/bin/sdkmanager` now.

Comment: @syslogic hmm, then it seems you want to do something else than what this question is about. I wanted to use the `android` command without GUI.

Answer (score 16):

You can update the sdk from command line by using the `-u` (no UI) option.

```
./android update sdk -u
```

Comment: that command blindly installs EVERYTHING  ... How to update just what's installed ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the Android IDE (which is Eclipse), you're going to need an X server to display it on. I'd recommend not trying to develop Android apps on a headless server, as you're going to need a display to use the IDE, and to run your app in the emulator, so that you can test it without flashing it to a device every time you change something.

If you want to develop the app without an X display, you're going to have to do everything by hand, which the IDE would normally do for you, and use an editor which doesn't require X, such as `vim` or `emacs`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! In the end I won't really develop apps on the server, I only want to build them there, sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

If you ssh -X in to the box and start android, it should use xserver on your machine. Sometimes I have to start another application e.g. Firefox to get the X working before I start android.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an old eclipse bug. It was related the JavaVM, you could try another VM if you can exclude that the issue is related to the X environment.

Answer (score 0):

In My case, I tried to install GTK packages (using 'sudo apt-get install') ,still error was coming repeatedly.

To identify error , Please check log path : /configuration/*.log

you will notice the stack trace present in error log emphasizes about display related issue. **Eclipse requires X server to be started so that User Interface loads properly. Root user by default doesn't start X-server.**

Hence I switched to another user and was able to open eclipse successfully.

```
root@anotheruser:/eclipse/configuration# exit
logout
anotheruser@anotheruser:~$ cd /eclipse/
anotheruser@anotheruser:/eclipse$ ./eclipse
```